# How many ways we can setup angular application in eclipse

Tags: angular

I am new to angular,
I just want to know how many ways we can create angular application in eclipse.

In most of the cases they are saying install angular IDE,
In some tutorial they are saying

Tools and Prerequisites

- Node.js and NPM — You will need to install this open-source JavaScript runtime environment and its package manager.
- Angular CLI — Install this handy command line interface for Angular.
  JDK and Eclipse for Java EE Developers — The Java EE IDE and tools I used in this example.
- TypeScript plugin for Eclipse — A typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript.
- Terminal plugin for Eclipse — A fully working command-line Terminal inside Eclipse.
- Basic TypeScript, HTML and Eclipse usage knowledge

these are enough, please guide me.

Comment: Just go to angular.io and follow the getting started guide..

Comment: Dear Mikeone , i want to work with dynamic web application ,there i have not found how to use it to work with angular using  eclipse without angular ide.

Comment: One of the best plugins for I've seen used in Eclipse for Node.js and Angular is [CodeMix](https://www.genuitec.com/products/codemix/)

Answer (score -1):

I think the best IDE to work with on Angular is Webstorm. you can create you app from there and it has some very nice features. another option for you is visual studio code. in my opinion don't use eclipse if you want to work with angular.

Comment: my requirement is with eclipse only,is there any solution

Comment: Although I agree with the statement in the answer (even though it's not really an answer), I don't understand your comment either. Why would it be a requirement to use a particular IDE, especially something like Eclipse? It doesn't affect the app in any way,.